# Filter using routes in REST API

Tags: rest, api

I am working on making changes to an existing Web API that exposes information about orders for specific customers.
As a developer, I am used to seeing "more or less" RESTful APIs, and I would expect the URL for getting customer's orders to look like this:

```
https://domain/orders-service/orders?customerId=<ID>
```

However, the current URL is this:

```
https://domain/orders-service/customers/<ID>/orders
```

To me, this seems confusing. When I see `customers/<ID>/orders` in the URL, I assume that if I omit `/orders` and request `customers/<ID>`, the API should give me customer's details in response. However, the existing API service knows nothing about customers (except that they have an ID that is attached to the order), and there is no endpoint that serves the `customers/<ID>` URL.

Is this a convention that I am unaware about where you can put `customers/<ID>` in your API URL, when there is no resource called `customer` in your API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a convention that I am unaware of where you can put customers/ in your API URL when there is no resource called customer in your API?

No. There's no convention.

You could support it tho. Say for convenience or backward compatibility. Nothing prevents you from implementing as many paths to the same resource as you want. But it would make the API misleading, as you are experiencing now.

If the domain of the given API has no `customer` resource or if it has it, but it's not meant to be public or discoverable, then the endpoint makes little sense.

I get the feeling that whoever set `customers/<ID>/orders` was probably following a rule of dumb (or convention he|she didn't understand). Or not. In any case, unless you can guarantee backward compatibility, I wouldn't remove it. In the worse scenario, I would suggest redirecting `customers/<ID>/orders` to `orders/?customerId=<ID>`

Answer (score 1):

REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers.

---

> When I see customers//orders in the URL, I assume that if I omit /orders and request customers/, the API should give me customer's details in response.

So part of the [REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) answer is that you don't do that: you don't try to guess the identifier of a resource that you want, but instead *follow links* to get to the resource that you want.  (Hypertext, rather than out of band information, drives interaction; see [Fielding 2008](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven)).

If we wanted, for example, to find the "parent document in a hierarchy of documents", then the right way to do that is to look at the available collection of links, find the link with the "up" relation, and then use the identifier described by the link target.

---

There are a reasons why, as a designer, you might prefer to encode customerId into the path part of the identifier, rather than into the query part.  Here are two that immediately spring to mind:

- Relative resolution: even when the resource model does not include a "parent" resource, you might still want to be able to use dot segments to describe other identifiers in the hierarchy (ie: using ../payments as a shorthand for `https://domain/orders-service/customers/<ID>/payments`)
- HTML forms: [HTML5 form processing](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110405/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#form-submission-algorithm) replaces the query part of the action URL with the query part computed from the form data set.

---

That all said, an API designer should still be considering whether its goals are better met by introducing an `https://domain/orders-service/customers/<ID>` resource that produces a useful representation rather than a general purpose error message.

It would be pretty reasonable, I think, to ask for the [decision record](https://cognitect.com/blog/2011/11/15/documenting-architecture-decisions) describing the motivations/constraints of the design.

Answer (score 0):

The convention people like to use is to put ids into the path rather than the query string. Like in your customer example `/customer/123` returns customer id 123

However, this convention soon falls down;

- When you have to pass more than one parameter. `customer/123/order/12/address` isn't really human discoverable or friendly. `customerOrder/123/12` doesn't show which id is which.
- If you have to pass string parameters your route binding can fail; does `/customer/address` return the customer with id 'address' or all customer addresses?
- When you have a list of parameters `/customers/1/2/3/4`

You are better off sending all parameters in the query string, except where you require lists which should be sent in the body due to length limitations on the url + path + query or complex objects which can be send in the body as json